Calculating Probabilities of hands in Texas Hold 'em
My question is how to calculate different probabilities of hands in Texas Hold 'em. I know how to do this for 5 card hands as this is much simpler. Wkipedia gives all the answers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability (Note this subtracts off the better hands from the one below it).
Additionally, I have read this page on how to find three of a kind: Calculating combinations of three of a kind in Texas Hold 'Em. Also, there is this that explains four of a kind, straight-flush, and full houses: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2006-2007/Probability/Texasholdem.pdf (Scroll to question 4).
Now I couldn't find how to do a Two-pair anywhere, so I tried the following.
First we have $$\binom{13}{2} \binom{4}{2}^2$$ to get us the number of the pairs and each pairs permutations.  This leaves 3 cards left. My first thought was just to subtract these 8 and then multiply by $\binom{44}{3}$. However this can let full-houses in, so we must subtract off the hands where all are the same kind. (Note we do allow a third pair to come in). Thus we subtract off $$\binom{11}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{13}{2}.$$
The last term is for each possible 2 pair. This still is over counting. I know it has to do with terms that are "3-pair". Subtracting off $$11(6)\binom{40}{1}$$
seems to account for these. Finally, I know we have to subtract the flush and straights that are possible, but these are quite rare and wouldn't account for how far off I am currently, so I assume there is a mistake in my initial subtracting. (I also am stuck on how to calculate flush and straights).
Thanks.

Choose a third, fourth, and fifth distinct rank to appear... then choose a suit for each.  Note that this might accidentally allow for straights or flushes (or both) and so should be adjusted further.  Another possibility though is three-pair which since we only keep the five best cards is treated as a two-pair.

Counting three-pairs you choose the three suits that get pairs... then choose the fourth suit.  $\binom{13}{3}\binom{4}{2}^240$, or the two-pair and three nonpair as $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}^211\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 4^3$

Your posted question glides over the question of relevance which is more a poker-analysis question than a math-analysis question.  For example, in a realistic poker setting, you typically don't care about situations where your hole cards are 2-3, and the flop comes 667-7-8, because then each of your opponents has (at least) 2 pair.  A more relevant question, given that you have 2-3, is whether the flop comes abc-d-e, where $~{a,b,c,d,e}~$ contains exactly one 2 and one 3, and there is no pair among the three other cards.

Yes, I was just trying to do the math, without the practical implications of having a two pair just in the community cards.
